# Variety with two different $\mathrm{mod}\:p$ fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ have two smooth projective models with non-isomorphic $\mathrm{mod}\:p$ fibers? Can the $\mathrm{mod}\:p$ fibers have different number of rational points?

I guess you can do blow-ups but let's impose some kind of minimality hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to question 1 is *yes*. Examples almost like what you are after can be found here:

[Does isomorphic generic fibre imply isomorphic special fibre for smooth morphisms?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75393/does-isomorphic-generic-fibre-imply-isomorphic-special-fibre-for-smooth-morphism)

Though admittedly the examples there are non-minimal as the generic fibre is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up in two points. But it is possible to come up with minimal examples as $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ can be specialised to both $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and a Hirzebruch surface; I can try to find the details if you would like.

The answer to question 2 is however *no*. The smooth proper base change theorem implies that the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the special fibres is isomorphic. Therefore the Weil conjectures implies that they have the same number of points modulo $p$.

Comment: Minor point: I think it's $\mathbf{P}^1\times \mathbf{P}^1$ that specializes to a Hirzebruch surface, not $\mathbf{P}^2$ (wrong Picard number).

Comment: Yes quite, thanks!